# Unable to change the Ranking Model used in SharePoint Online

Tags: powershell, ranking, sharepoint-online

I'm in a SharePoint Online tenancy that has an Office 365 Business Essential license.  As I understand, the managing of the Ranking Model is done through the SharePoint Online Management Shell.  I've downloaded the application and am able to login into our tenancy without error.

Everything I've found online to help me either change or even check the configuration of the Ranking Model results in an error that the term is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet.

Example:
https://yuriburger.net/2011/08/25/changing-sharepoint-2010-search-ranking-model/

States I can check which models are registered with our Search Service Application by entering the following cmdlet.

```
Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingModel -SearchApplication "Search Service Application"
```

I receive the following error.

```
*Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingModel : The term 'Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingModel' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingModel -SearchApplication "Search Service Applicatio ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingMo
   del:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException*
```

In addition, if I enter "Help" it provides a list of available cmdlets, the cmdlets the documentation I find aren't ever listed.  If I try to enter a help `Get-SPEnterpriseSearchRankingModel` or other recommended cmdlets, I receive a stackoverflow error message and the Shell module crashes.

Am I getting these results because of the limitations of the Business Essentials license or do I just not have something installed?

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj819267.aspx#bkmk_Featurecomparison

The SharePoint features across Office 365 plans reference states that in order for me to [u]create[/u] or [u]customize[/u] the ranking model I must install the Rank Model Tuning app.  I'm just seeing about changing the ranking model being used with another of the existing ranking models.
Sidenote: Attempts to install that app are failing for an unknown reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sharepoint Online doesn't support that cmdlet. See list of available cmdlets: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fp161364.aspx

In fact, there are very few PowerShell cmdlets for Sharepoint Online. This is probably due to the fact that it's a lot more complicated to write cmdlets for the server-infrastructure in Azure/O365  vs. on-premise Exchange 2013 with direct database-access.

See this article for comparison between Sharepoint 2013 and Sharepoint Online. It's from 2013, but looking at the cmdlets-list on TechNet, it doesn't look like much has changed: https://blog.blksthl.com/2013/01/15/sharepoint-2013-powershell-cmdlets-listed-onprem-vs-online/#365

Looks like you would have to do this using the Admin Center (GUI).

Comment: I'm not familiar with something called the "Administration Console".

I'm aware of the Admin Center that is available with the Business Essentials license, and the Center Administration that is available with higher level licenses.  Are you referring to either of these?  I've been searching the corners of the Admin Center, without success, which drove me to the SharePoint Online Management Shell module.

Comment: SharePoint Online admin center (https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Find-content-about-the-SharePoint-Online-admin-center-887d34fd-7c6b-4323-9e1a-4b479f2aa277?omkt=en-US&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US). Manage result sources: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Manage-result-sources-fd8d6ac6-c5d0-454d-80a9-51580902b25d